# Set string to pasteboard (copy, paste) in cocoa application

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, macos

How can i set a string so the user can paste it somewhere else in a cocoa objective c application?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

See the [Pasteboard Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/cocoa/Conceptual/PasteboardGuide106/Articles/pbCopying.html). You specifically want the section on "Copying to a Pasteboard."

Comment: Thanks, but it doesn't say how to get an NSPasteboardTypeString??

Answer (score 18):

```
[pboard declareTypes:[NSArray arrayWithObject:NSStringPboardType] owner:self];
[pboard setString:@"Unbelievable" forType:NSStringPboardType];
```

If you are targeting OS X 10.6 and higher only, use `NSPasteboardTypeString` instead of `NSStringPboardType`.

Answer (score 5):

```
[[NSPasteboard generalPasteboard] declareTypes:[NSArray arrayWithObject:NSStringPboardType] owner:nil];
[[NSPasteboard generalPasteboard] setString:@"My Text" forType:NSStringPboardType];
```

[reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/cocoa/Conceptual/PasteboardGuide106/Articles/pbCopying.html)

Answer (score 4):

This is the way you do if you're targeting OSX 10.6 or higher:

```
NSPasteboard *pasteboard = [NSPasteboard generalPasteboard];
[pasteboard clearContents];
[pasteboard writeObjects:@[@"Some string"]];
```

For more information see the [Pasteboard Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/PasteboardGuide106/Articles/pbCopying.html) on Apple's site.